# How to fix "express is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed express but I have this error

```
var express= require ('express');
var app = express();
var ejs =require('ejs');
var port= 3000
 app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    res.render('/form.ejs');
    });
    app.listen(3000);
 module.exports= app;
```

Comment: Looks like you are using an older version of the express. Check the version in package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of express you are using is most probably outdated.

Remove `express": "^<version>"` from package.json and use the following command to install the latest version of express.

```
npm install --save express
```

Or you could also set `express": "latest"` in the package.json file and run the command `nom install` to install the latest version.